# In the process of installing Java and Hadoop, my user profile has disappeared?

Tags: java, hadoop, .profile

So I added the following code to the bottom of profile after:

```
sudo gedit etc/profile
```

Code added to profile:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_20
PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/{user_name}/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1
PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

OK - so no problem.  I saved, closed, and went back to terminal and didn't think I did anything that would somehow delete the whole profile.  But, that's what seems to have happened??  Now when I do gedit etc/profile code, the whole thing is completely blank?  Sorry if I'm just not looking in the right place and this is a stupid question.

**EDIT:**

So when I do edit profile code, it's a different profile.  The original one is indeed intact; at least I can open it from the text editor.  But how can I reopen the original (proper) profile?  Every time I try

```
sudo gedit etc/profile
```

It brings up a NEW, blank profile.  Did I add those Java/Hadoop paths to the right profile in the first place?  Must it be a certain profile within a certain directory (and is the directory when I enter the above line of code the determinant of the sole location where the profile exists/applies?)

Answer (score 1):

Okay so here are a couple of points for for what you're doing wrong and how you should fix it:

1. The command you're supposed to run is `sudo gedit /etc/profile`, not `etc/profile`. That `/` before `etc` is very crucial. The command you are executing is trying to open another file, and if that file doesn't exist, you'll see a completely blank page like the one you're seeing.

   > *Note:* you shouldn't be using `sudo` with `gedit`. Use `gksu gedit /etc/profile`. If that gives you an error, use `sudo nano /etc/profile` instead. This will not open up a pretty text editor like gedit, but it will allow you to edit the file from inside the terminal. To save your changes and close, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. If you don't want to save your changes, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>N</kbd>.
2. You shouldn't actually be using `/etc/profile`. It's better to add the code you're trying to copy into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` (which is the same as `/home/YourUserName/.bashrc` and `/home/YourUserName/.profile`). So you edit that file using `gksu gedit ~/.bashrc` or `sudo nano ~/.bashrc` (and the same for the other `.profile` file).
3. You have a few mistakes in the code you're trying to copy. It should look like this:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20
   JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_20
   HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/YourUserName/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1
   PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
   export JAVA_HOME
   export JRE_HOME
   export HADOOP_INSTALL
   export PATH
   ```

   You have to obviously change **`YourUserName`** to your actual username.

So, continue with whatever guide you're following and you should be set.